# Security Context for Kubernetes pod probes

Tags: kubernetes

Wondering what security context is used by Kubernetes for readiness and liveness probes. I'm using EXEC type to run a script as part of the probes. Does pod security context apply to probes as well?

Comment: The whole talk is according to my view. It should be apply to probes too. Because as probe you want to exec command in the container and the security context is for container. That's why they are applicable to probes too.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your probe implementation?

Comment: @VAS, it is nothing but a typical probe described on Kubernetes website.